# Object of instance not set to an instance or an object. Visual Basic

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, vba

I am writing a simple piece to insert 5 values into my local database. The connection gets established well but when I press the button , which does the job for inserting into the DB I get "Object of instance not set to an instance or an object" this message.

Sql version
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)

Here is My code

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
Dim ID As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=DIONISIS-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Testing;Trusted_Connection=True;"
                                         }
    Dim SQLcmd As SqlCommand
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        Label2.Text = "Connected"


    Catch ex As Exception
        Label2.Text = "ERROR"
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        SQLCon.Close()

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=DIONISIS-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Testing;Trusted_Connection=True;"
                                         }
    Dim SQLcmd As SqlCommand
    ID += 1
    Dim LastName As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim firstName As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim Address As String = TextBox3.Text
    Dim city As String = TextBox4.Text
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLcmd.Connection = SQLCon 'EDIT: The problem seems to be here'
        SQLcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO students([student_ID], [LastName],[FirstName],[Address],[City]) VALUES([ID], [LastName],[firstName],[Address],[city])"
        SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        SQLCon.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `VALUES([ID], [LastName],[firstName],[Address],[city])`

Comment: @Devart check the edit above Thanks

Comment: `SQLcmd` has not been instantiated

Comment: @Jamiec Jesus..... you are right. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate `SQLcmd` before trying to set properties on it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
SQLcmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO students([student_ID], [LastName],      
[FirstName],[Address],[City]) VALUES({1},'{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}'"),LastName       
,firstName,Address,city)
```

**BUT** you will be prone to SQL Injection. The correct way to do this is described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx) and it's name is by using SQL Parameters

Comment: well it did not work... It seems that this line has the problem.
            SQLcmd.Connection = SQLCon